# What type of continuous function will be differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I know that every differentiable function is continuous but converse is not true. So how I can say that a continuous function will be differentiable. That a continuous function will be differentiable when and what special characteristic property it would be?

Comment: OK,! I answer your previous question!

Comment: The differentiable ones ;) There is no reduction of differentiability to other simpler properties. Contrast this with Riemann integrable functions, which do have a neat characterization.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiability is it's own property, a function $f: D \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable on $D$ if and only if for all $a \in D$, $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists. Recall that for $f$ to be continuous on $D$, we need that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ so it should be kind of intuitive from this of why we must have continuity for differentiability. As for the converse take a look at the Weierstrass function here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function . It is continuous on all of $\mathbb R$ but differentiable nowhere!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not!
Search for Peano curve. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve
There are some another examples, one of them presented in W. Rubin "Principles of Mathematical Analysis"(1976) pp. 153-154. He described a function which is the limit of a sequence of functions.
For your edited alternative of your question you may think about "Jagged Curves" or curves which has some "Returning" points.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is absolutely continuous (which is stronger than continuous), then is differentiable almost everyhere. Now, if $f$ Lipschitz, then is absolutely continuos. Then $f$ is is differentiable almost everyhere. So, a simpler condition is that $f$ be Lipschitz (however, note that in general $f$ won't be differetiable everywhere).